# For Loop Alternative on large data frame that runs a different filter with each iteration

Tags: r

I'm running a loop that takes the ranking from R1[i] and filters a data frame of all rankings in the specified range and at the same time filtering a different column R2[i] to find the ranking of an opponent so I end up with a new data frame that only includes matches that involve players in those specific ranking ranges so that I can find the mean of a column for only those matches.

For Example: Player 1 is Ranked 10th and Player 2 is Ranked 34th. The following code takes every match including players ranked between 5-15 +/- 20% of 10 and players ranked between 29-39 +/- 20% of 34.

Then it finds the mean of Data_Dif and returns to the initial DF in row [i] and does so for every row.

This code works fine but it's a bit messy and it takes 4 hours to run 57,000 matches. Does anyone have a faster solution please? I have to run this every day.

```
Rank <- Data %>% filter(between(R1, Data$R1[i]-5-(Data$R1[i]*0.2), Data$R1[i]+5+(Data$R1[i]*0.2)) | between(R1, Data$R2[i]-5-(Data$R2[i]*0.2), Data$R2[i]+5+(Data$R2[i]*0.2))) 
%>% filter(between(R2, Data$R1[i]-5-(Data$R1[i]*0.2), Data$R1[i]+5+(Data$R1[i]*0.2)) | between(R2, Data$R2[i]-5-(Data$R2[i]*0.2), Data$R2[i]+5+(Data$R2[i]*0.2))) 
Rank_Difference <- Data$Rank_Dif[i]
Rank <- Rank %>% filter(Rank_Dif >= Rank_Difference-5)
Data$Rank_Adv[i] <- mean(Rank$Data_Dif)
}

Data
     R1   R2 Rank_Dif Data_Dif    Rank_Adv
1     2    1        1   -0.272 0.037696970
2    10   34       24    0.377 0.146838617
3    10   29       19    0.373 0.130336232
4     2    5        3    0.134 0.076242424
5    34   17       17   -0.196 0.094226519
6     1   18       17    0.144 0.186158879
7    17   25        8    0.264 0.036212219
8    42   18       24    0.041 0.102343915
9     5   13        8   -0.010 0.091952381
10   34   21       13   -0.226 0.060790576
11    2   14       12    0.022 0.122350649
12   10  158      148    0.330 0.184901961
13   11    1       10   -0.042 0.109918367
14   29   52       23    0.463 0.054469108
15   10 1000      990    0.628 0.437600000
16   17  329      312    0.445 0.307750000
17   11   20        9    0.216 0.072621875
18  417  200      217   -0.466 0.106737401
19    5   53       48    0.273 0.243890710
20   14    7        7   -0.462 0.075739414
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, perhaps starting with the output of `dput(head(Data))` and describing the structure of the rest -- eg how many players?

Comment: This sounds like you want a "non-equi join" which can be done using `data.table` or `sqldf`, among others. For smallish data this can also be done adequately in `dplyr` or `fuzzyjoin` by creating a cartesian join of all the possible combinations and then filtering out the ones that aren't matches.

Comment: Hi Jon, the structure of data is in the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Aexr.png) provided. I will add another image that shows a sample of what the data should look like. Thank you.

Comment: Images are a less useful way to share data, since it won't reflect data formats, it requires me to retype it to make my own object, and it can't be read by screen readers.

Comment: apologies, I have edited for you now.